# Workflows lost on SharePoint 2010 migration

Tags: workflow, upgrade

I have been migrating SharePoint 2007 to a SharePoint 2010 installation.

The upgrade completes successfully but the association between workflows and lists is lost.

In the SharePoint 2007 there are workflows "Approval" and "Collect Feedback" on all lists. After the upgrade the following message appears for all lists on SharePoint 2010: "There are no workflows currently available to start on this item"

The only way I can see to get these back is to go through each list indiviually and reapply workflows - I wish to avoid this as there's hundreds of lists.

All workflow features have been activated. It is the enterprise edition.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the workflows were out of the box ones which were associated with the lists , then please go through the following wonderful article that discusses in depth about workflows and SharePoint 2007 to 2010 migration.

http://www.the14folder.com/2010/07/25/migrating-workflows-question/

Incase if they were custom workflows deployed as solutions , the following is the best practice to achieve the same in the following sequence.

1) Ensure all your custom webparts are changed to make them SP 2010 compatible.
2) Deploy all workflows as features first before restoring the site.
3) Activate the workflows on the target site collection.
4) Restore the migrated site by attaching the content database of SP 2007.
5) Verify the workflow states for the migrated site.

If all else fails , try to migrate the site on a different SP 2007 farm first and check if the problem persists in that scenario as well. This can give you a good insight on what exactly is wrong with the workflows.

Comment: please remove the link above which does not seems to be valid anymore or hijacked.